# How do I make a audio play onclicked with one thumbnailed image HTML

Tags: html, css

This is my code so if you can help me it'd be great thank's StackOverflow

```
<head>
<script>
function play(){
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="SoundWave.gif" width="200" height="200" value="play" onclick="play();">
<audio id="audio" src="01.mp3"></audio>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors with your code?

Comment: You mean you need only one image to toggle between pause/play?

Comment: OK, you simply have to check if the audio is paused, then play it, else, pause it

Comment: @EhsanT how do I do that, I'm pretty new to the website formatting I'm making an audio playlist I'll show you my new code

Comment: Just for your concern, I've posted an answer!

Comment: Thank's and do you think you can help me make it a playlist

Comment: Actually SO is not a good place to ask for code samples, you have to write your does and if you had some errors or problems with your code, ask your question here. But you can check [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WsXX3/33/) which may give you a good insight on how to implement an `html5` audio player + a playlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need will be something like this:

```
<head>
<script>
function play(){
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("audio");
  if(myAudio.paused)
    myAudio.play();
  else
    myAudio.pause();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="SoundWave.gif" width="200" height="200" onclick="play();">
<audio id="audio" src="01.mp3"></audio>
</body>
```

you can get more information about `html5 audio element` and how to work with it using [this link](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio)

P.S. `<img>` tag does not have a `value` property